# AngularJS: Controllers / Services should be Pascal Case? (using Yo in yeoman)

Tags: angularjs, yeoman

I have started using Yo (yeoman) to scaffold my controllers, services etc for angularjs.

I normally do a

```
  yo angular:service passwordService
```

I am using camel case as this is the name of the file it creates but I have noticed it also uses the same name for the name of the service  so

```
passwordService
```

rather than

```
PasswordService
```

What are the best practices here?

Thanks

Answer (score 21):

It's worth noting that in the [Developer Guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services) in many places (including the linked-to "services" section), the AngularJS devs use camelcase + first lowercase for names of services and other things. So maybe you would consider that a best practice for AngularJS.

That said, I think from other languages it is more common to name services and classes with camelcase + first **uppercase** and actually as it turns out in JavaScript this seems to be of especial importance. Consider that you have a class named `user`—then what would you call a variable that contains an instance of `user`? You couldn't call it `user` without extremely awkward/error-prone shadowing.

In AngularJS, your `$resource` services will end up becoming your classes in OO JavaScript "of old." Look:

```
angular.module('Foo', [], function() {}).factory('User', function() {
  var User = $resource('/api/user');

  User.prototype.getFullName = function() {
    return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
  };

  return User;
});
```

See where I'm going with this? You will eventually inject your new `User` `$resource` and instantiate it:

```
function MyController($scope, User) {
  var someNewUser = new User();
};
```

Or you will want to iterate over several users using a simple var name like `user` for the current item:

```
angular.forEach(someUsers, function(user) {
  // Good thing you didn't name your $resource "user"!
  // Weird/undesirable shadowing would result here then...
});
```

Let me know if you need more clarification as to why I believe best practice is first **uppercase** for class/service names given the context of JavaScript. (For contrast, consider that in PHP var names are prefixed with `$`, therefore shadowing can't happen between var names and class names. $User = new User() is perfectly fine.)

Of course, you could do `User = new user()` in JS but that would be just about opposite the standards of existing languages/style guides.

Comment: I've noticed a trend of naming Factories and Services with first uppercase, and providers with first lower case. Not exactly sure why.

Comment: The word you are looking for is PascalCase.

Answer (score 15):

For Javascript conventions, you should only use `PascalCase` if and only if the related function is a `constructor` function. *(i.e. must be called with `new`)*. It is important becase it lets the programmers to know that one has to use `new`, otherwise `this` property will be messed up.

For factories and providers etc, you should actually use `camelCase` convention.

### Update

While my initial claim holds still in JS environment outside of Angular, I now think it is better to use `PascalCase` for injected variables. This has been the convention for a long time and it's not worth fighting back. Since injected variables are almost always singletons and are application wide, it feels right to differ them from the local variables created in the function's scope.

Comment: Technically nothing prevents factories or providers from returning a function that could be called with "new" as a constructor. I generally agree though that convention would make sense to use camelCase. However since you will usually use the ['Service', function(service) { }] notation it is kind of moot. The function variable can be either case.

Comment: This is IMO the best answer.

Comment: @UmurKontacı - After working with AngularJS pretty heavily for a while now, I no longer understand why capitalization makes the most sense for controllers / services.  JavaScript convention says that the function constructor should be PascalCase, however the reference to the 'newed' object is generally camelCase.  To me it makes sense that the function generating a controller should be named something like "function MyService() {}", however since angular is doing the assignment "myService = new MyService()", shouldn't it be bound to a camelCase variable when defined?

Comment: @ColeChamberlain The naming convention for instances and local variables is camelCase, that's right. On the other hand, if a module exports an object (e.g. React, Backbone), it is OK for them to be named PascalCase, regardless whether they were instantiated or simple objects. I think you can make arguments for both of those cases. The important thing is to pick one and be consistent throughout the project so as not to confuse other devs.